# Function that checks DB, returns message, and also sends email

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In this example I am using MySQL, which I know is deprecated, but this is just for learning purposes. I am also learning how to use PDO and right now just dont wanna mess up fue to my inexperience with PDO so I am using mysql right now.

Ok, so I have a jQuery AJAX function that submits a form data to a PHP function page. The PHP page then communicates with the Database and returns a result. All of this works so far.

A user fills out a form supplying their email address. The email is passed to teh PHP page and entered into the DB. If the user exists, a message is displayed telling them that they are already subscribed. If the do not exits, they are added and then a message tells them they have been successfully added. The GOOD NEWS is all of this works great!

Now, where I have an issue is that during that same callback function "dispAdd", I want to generate an automated welcome email to the user. No matter how I try to code the mail call though, I seem to get an error in the function. I am going to give you what I have right now but if someone can help that would be hugely appreciated.

Here is my callback function because all the other pieces work ok right now:

```
function dispAdd()             // Serves as callback function to jQuery/AJAX in contact.html
{
  $sql= "SELECT * FROM mailList WHERE email = '$email'";
  $result= mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  $to = "rmailloux11@mail.bristol.mass.edu";
  $who = "ME";
  $message = "WOW";
  $subject = "TESTING";
  $message = $who . ', ' . $message;
  $headers = "From: rmailloux11@mail.bristol.mass.edu" . "\r\n";

  if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)  // Checks to see if query returns any info for the calling function
  {
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    return;
  }
}
```

Original CALL:

```
$('#contForm').submit(function() {
  var formData = $(this).serialize();            // Stores all form data in AJAX variable
  $.post('contact.php',formData,dispAdd);
  function dispAdd(result) {               // Callback function requests result of RESULT
    if (!result) {
      $('#main').html('<div>Your have been added to the mailing list</div>');
    } else {
      if ($('#fail').length==0) {
        $('#main').append('<div id="fail" style="color:red";>This email address is already subscribed to our mailing list</div>');
      }
    }
  }
  return false;    // Stops form from loading contact.php page
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you could post the error as well?

Comment: The only error that happens when I reformat is that sometimes my return will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
  $('#contForm').submit(function()
  {
    var formData = $(this).serialize();            // Stores all form data in AJAX variable
    $.post('contact.php',formData, function(data)
    {
      console.log(data);
      if(data)
      {
        $('#main').html('<div>You have been added to the mailing list</div>');
      }
      else
      {
        $('#main').append('<div id="fail" style="color:red";>This email address is already subscribed to our mailing list</div>');
      }
      console.log(data);
    });
    return false;    // Stops form from loading contact.php page
  });
</script>
```

Then, in contact.php you should put the below function:

```
function dispAdd()             // Serves as callback function to jQuery/AJAX in contact.html
{
  $sql= "SELECT * FROM mailList WHERE email = '$email'";
  $result= mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  $to = "rmailloux11@mail.bristol.mass.edu";
  $who = "ME";
  $message = "WOW";
  $subject = "TESTING";
  $message = $who . ', ' . $message;
  $headers = "From: rmailloux11@mail.bristol.mass.edu" . "\r\n";

  if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)   // Checks to see if query returns any info for the calling function
  {
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    return;
  }
}
```

After the code on contact.php runs, have it call the `dispAdd` function and return the result of `dispAdd` to your Ajax request.

Comment: I am using the DB, just n ot for this examplle.... what you are seeing is an alteration of what I IWLL be using which is why i repopd the TO.

Comment: Yes the mail is setup and works fine with other pages exactly where this is

Comment: I've added "if, else" statements to ensure the code you (think) is being called, is actually being called. It's possible the query is returning no users, when you think it is. If that's the case, there may be a slight issue with the query. The echo statements just let you know where the code is getting to.

Comment: Yes I see that but you are totally eliminating the RETURN that is needed for other process of the page output. I need both pieces to work together so that the DB is queried, returns a result (is the email already registered), passes that back to the CALL, and also sends an email.

Comment: The query works fine. The probelm is strictly within this function. The function must have a return, it must loop through results to process that return, and it must send an email. The only part not working is the email. I may have to figure out a way to do more than one function.

Comment: @RobertMailloux you need to use "echo" to send data back to the ajax function. I'll edit my code including your recent edits.

Comment: You are missing what I am saying. The AJAX works fine. It is ONLY the email I have the issue with. EVERYTHING else is working just fine. If I remove my mail code, the page works properly. It is only when I add THAT code I have an issue.